# Add Calendar to StackPanel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Is there any way I can add my Google calendar to a StackPanel?

```
function calendar(app){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('calendar');
}

**** HTML FILE ****
<html>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=davie.k12.nc.us_d2mv2eb8aspuant1vb5j6r3sis%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/New_York" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull out the events dates, titles, details you want and build that into a custom view but if you're referring to just adding the calendar url to that particular panel, it won't show up.  You may be able to iframe it with HtmlService.

```
function doGet() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(YOUR_CAL_NAME)[0];
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createStackPanel();
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7 * 86400000);
  var events = cal.getEvents(start, end);
  var tz = cal.getTimeZone();
  var i, len, html = '';

  for (i = 0, len = events.length; i < len; i++) {
    html += events[i].getTitle() + ' ' + Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), tz, 'MM-dd-yyyy') + '<br>';
  }

  panel.add(app.createHTML(html));
  app.add(panel);

  return app;
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but keep getting an error.  I must be doing something incorrect... can you help?

Comment: What's the error? iframe route might not work as it's on the [restricted list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-caja?hl=en)

Comment: ERROR: Cannot find method add(HtmlOutput).

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to mix UiApp and HTML service... certainly not by trying to add html content to a uiApp widget. I've read a post about that (by a Googler) but right now I can't remember when /where... sorry

Comment: What would be the best way to get a calendar function in the stack panel, or am I just dreaming...

Comment: What would be the best way to get a calendar function in the stack panel, or am I just dreaming...  I am trying to add a calendar, form, and HTML into a stack-like panel. Is there a possible work around if stack panel is not the best option?

Comment: Just throw a link to the calendar in the panel. `var anchor = UiApp.createAnchor('Calendar', calendar.getUrl())`

Comment: Could someone show me an example of pulling the events from my calendar each day and displaying them a week at a time. I am having a hard time locating anything on how to accomplish this task but I think it would serve my purpose in the stackpanel if I could integrate it.

Comment: i've now provided an UiApp ex. in my answer

Comment: Thanks... I believe I can work with this to make it work like I want it too.  It's better than nothing.

Comment: If the app is ultimately being embedded inside a Google Site, then there's always the Calendar gadget that can be inserted into the same page.